# Queries Regarding SSL Certification and Online Payment Gateway

Tags: ssl-certificate, payment-gateway

I am developing a event website ( on php and mysql ) which requires online payment for event registration. The payment gateway we have purchased from a bank. The bank asks us to have SSL certificate for our website.. As banks websites usually have Verisign certificate therefore the people with whom we had a conversation told us to have verisign SSL certificate on our event website

When i checked Verisign.com then i found that there are many types of certificates available.

1. Secure Site Pro with EV
2. Secure Site with EV
3. Secure Site Pro
4. Secure Site

I want to know, is it enough to have the most basic of all.. what difference does it make with different options which are available with verisign. i still believe that the people at the bank have no knowledge of other companies providing SSL certificates. So can i use godaddy or other SSL Certificate providers instead of Verisign.

please help if anyone have worked with payment gateways and SSL Certificates..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any SSL certificate you want. The SSL certificate and payment gateway are independent of each other and one does not directly affect the other. So you can use Godaddy or any other SSL provider you want with your payment gateway.

Comment: oh! thank you very much for the info. does this also mean "having more features in the ssl certificate only increases the trust level and level of security... and overall working will be the same."